# JPA Criteria API and type safety

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api, type-safety

I seem to have missed something in JPA's criteria API and its type safety.  Consider the following code:

```
@Entity
@Access(FIELD)
class User(

  @Id
  Long id;

  @Column(unique=true)
  String email;

  String password;
}
```

Here the meta model:

```
@StaticMetamodel(User.class)
public static class User_ {
  public static volatile SingularAttribute<User, Long> id;
  public static volatile SingularAttribute<User, String> email;
  public static volatile SingularAttribute<User, String> password;
}
```

Then some code to exercise the class, built using pages from [the Java EE Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjiup.html):

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<User> cq = cb.createQuery(User.class);
Root<User> user = cq.from(User.class);
cq.select(user);
cq.where(cb.equal(user.get(User_.email), "john@google.com")); //this line is my problem

TypedQuery<User> q = em.createQuery(cq);
List<User> allUsers = q.getResultList();

assertEquals(1, allUsers.size());
```

It works fine.  However, if I change the "where" clause to use an Integer instead of a String ("john@google.com"), I expected the code to not compile.  Yet it compiles fine.

I thought the criteria API was supposed to be type safe?  That is hardly more type safe than the following, using standard JPQL.  I mean, what is the purpose of the meta model in the above code?? I have gained nothing from it.

```
User u = em.createQuery("select u from User u where u.email = :email", User.class)
           .setParameter("email", "john@google.com")
       .getSingleResult();
```

So the question is: can I make the criteria API query more type safe, so that I can only pass a String to the "from" clause?

Comment: PS. I appreciate that the "equals" method should be able to take objects rather than just the type it is comparing to, because the database is able to cast too.

Comment: You also gain the certainty that you haven't mistyped the name you assigned to the property and will be able to find code using this specific field (and not a field by the same name of an other entity)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Type safety is restricted to the upper bound of the generic type of the `Expression<T>` interface, not the exact type defined in the metamodel. So, because
`CriteriaBuilder.equal(Expression<?> x, java.lang.Object y)` takes an argument of type `Expression<?>` it allows to pass any object for comparison.

The other `CriteriaBuiler` methods are more type safe, for example `CriteriaBuilder.ge(Expression<? extends java.lang.Number> x, Expression<? extends java.lang.Number> y)` allows only numbers. But allows to compare an integer field with a float for example.

You can't do better than this. The methods should have been something like `CriteriaBuilder.equal(Expression<T> x, T y)` with T being the field type from the metamodel.

Of course this is a hole in the type safety of the criteria API. I don't know why the JPA API creators choosed the wildcard version of these methods.

Comment: I assume the wildcard-approach is partly because the expressions will(/could) be evaluated by the database and said database may have conversions handy like `String` may be comparable to `byte[]` and numbers (e.g. MySQL can compare `String` to mostly anything). Also if you look at regular Java-objects `equals()` may be called for any `Object` (but will most likely only return true for same class). Because of all this I think the decision is good and leaves us with the possibilities described in my answer to force strict typing.

Comment: @TheConstructor Yes, I exaggerated a bit, it's not really a hole, but rather a design decision to allow more flexible comparisons with the downside of catching less compile time errors. Bad or good is debatable.

Comment: This way strict wrappers are possible. Guess we won't change the specs by tomorrow and have to handle the current implementation. ;-) Last pro argument on my list is that without using the static model you ofzen only get ?-properties and Java would than most probably infer non-working type parameters at compile time.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want strict type-matching you can use [in()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#in%28javax.persistence.criteria.Expression%29) and your query would look like the following:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<User> cq = cb.createQuery(User.class);
Root<User> user = cq.from(User.class);
cq.select(user);
cq.where(cb.in(user.get(User_.email)).value("john@google.com"));

TypedQuery<User> q = em.createQuery(cq);
List<User> allUsers = q.getResultList();

assertEquals(1, allUsers.size());
```

or you could even write

```
cq.where(cb.in(user.get(User_.email)).value(cq.literal("john@google.com")));
```

While there are differences between using `equal()` and an `in()`-clause with only one value this achieves strict typing according to your static type model. Most database engines will optimize `=` and `in()` with one value in the same way.

If you don't like to switch `equal()` for `in()` you can also write functions like this to ensure your compiler alerts you of possible mistypings

```
static <T> Predicate equal(CriteriaBuilder cb, Expression<T> left, T right) {
    return cb.equal(left, right);
}

static <T> Predicate equal(CriteriaBuilder cb, Expression<T> left, Expression<T> right) {
    return cb.equal(left, right);
}
```

Lastly wether you like to use your own `equal()`-wrapper or switch to `in()` you may need the `toLong()`,... functions of `CriteriaBuilder` more often as the `Number`-objects aren't very cast-compatible and it is normally better to let the database handle integer-width changes.

Answer (score 0):

cq.where(booelan , String)
Java commits **"implicit type casting of numbers to strings".**
The integer is directly fed to initialize a methods String type argument , so therefore it is a legitimate string.
Around the only place and way in the language that problem could ever occur. You will simply be required to check the address syntax for validity first and consider how to handle such a problem if it occurs.

Comment: I'm using Eclipselink 2.3.2 and there is no "where" method on cq which takes a boolean and a String.  There is only cq.where(Expression<Boolean>) and cq.where(Predicate).  What is "implicity type casting"?

Comment: -1 for incorrect information: Java does not convert implicitly from numbers to strings